# UIImage not appearing in a TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a UIImage appear in a TableView. I have created a struct please see below:

```
struct City {
let name: String
let coordinates: (lat: Double, lon: Double)
let image: UIImage
```

}

In my MasterTableViewController I have created the following Array.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cities = []

    let london = City(name: "Melbourne", coordinates: (-37.8436, 144.9510), image:UIImage(named: "Australia.png")!)
    let melbourne = City(name: "Sepang", coordinates: (2.7623, 101.7386), image:UIImage(named: "Malaysia.png")!)
    let china = City(name: "Shanghai", coordinates: (31.2304,121.4737), image:UIImage(named: "China.png")!)
    let saopaulo = City(name: "Bahrain", coordinates: (26.0316,50.5129), image:UIImage(named: "Qatar.png")!)
    let nurbergring = City(name: "Barcelona", coordinates: (41.5666,2.2642), image:UIImage(named: "Spain.png")!)
    let monaco = City(name: "Monaco", coordinates: (-35.0617, 138.6155), image:UIImage(named: "France.png")!)
    let canada = City(name: "Canada", coordinates: (45.5066, -73.5242), image:UIImage(named: "Canada.png")!)
    let austria = City(name: "Austria", coordinates: (47.2234, 14.7606), image:UIImage(named: "Austria.png")!)
    let british = City(name: "Silverstone", coordinates: (52.0753, -1.0155), image:UIImage(named: "United Kingdom.png")!)
    let hungary = City(name: "Hungaroring", coordinates: (47.5829, 19.2486), image:UIImage(named: "HUngary.png")!)
    let belgium = City(name: "Belgium", coordinates: (50.4370, 5.9680), image:UIImage(named: "Belgium.png")!)
    let italy = City(name: "Monza", coordinates: (45.6140, 9.2823), image:UIImage(named: "Italy.png")!)
    let singapore = City(name: "Singapore", coordinates: (1.2842, 103.8583), image:UIImage(named: "Singapore.png")!)
    let japan = City(name: "Suzuka", coordinates: (34.8410, 136.5550), image:UIImage(named: "Japan.png")!)
    let russian = City(name: "Sochi", coordinates: (43.6028, 39.7341), image:UIImage(named: "Russia.png")!)
    let usa = City(name: "Circuit of the Americas", coordinates: (30.1384, -97.6352), image:UIImage(named: "United States.png")!)
    let mexico = City(name: "Mexico", coordinates: (19.4326, -99.1332), image:UIImage(named: "Mexico.png")!)
    let brazil = City(name: "Brazil", coordinates: (-23.5505, -46.6333), image:UIImage(named: "Brazil.png")!)
    let abudhabi = City(name: "Yas Marina Circuit", coordinates: (24.4729, 54.6063), image:UIImage(named: "Qatar.png")!)
```

I am not sure I should have added a UIImage to the cell in the storyboard and then created a separate array for the png files?  Or should I have just added the UIImage.
Also, the images are flag icons as I have done these as 44*44 pixels. Is this the right specs for adding images in a tableView Cell?

Comment: What do you have in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where you use the cities created in that ViewDidLoad function...

Anyway, I think the best way would be to have an array of cities, where you append all those cities to. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you use that Array.

Some basic sample code for your MasterTableViewController to get you underway

```
class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController

@IBOutlet var peopleTable: UITableView! // make sure you connect the outlet from your Storyboard

var cities = [city]()

func loadCities () {
    cities.append (City(name: "Melbourne", coordinates: (-37.8436, 144.9510), image:UIImage(named: "Australia.png")!))
    cities.append (City(name: "Sepang", coordinates: (2.7623, 101.7386), image:UIImage(named: "Malaysia.png")!))
    //... for all the cities
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadCities ()
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell (style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell") as! myCustomCell
    cell.myTextLabel = cities[indexPath.row].name
    cell.myImageView = cities[indexPath.row].image
    //... other cell properties
```

}

Make sure you have myTextLabel, myImageView defined in your storyboard and connected to Outlets in your myCustomCell

Comment: Hi Glenn thanks for the reply. This is what I have in my tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath function. ` override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        let city = cities?[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = city?.name
        return cell
    }`

Comment: first look it seems ok, but it's hard to tell where stuff goes wrong as I don't see the whole picture like Storyboard and other code

Comment: What I had done is a basic cell in the Storyboard. So I would have to have a custom cell to add the UIImage? Then create a UILabel? So will this change the cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: Hi Glenn, if I make a custom cell then I am going to have to create a tableviewcell sub class.  Is there not a way of adding a UIImage to the basic cell.  I created a struct as I have mentioned above.

Comment: afaik not, that's not a std cell

Comment: So do I create a custom cell?

Comment: Thanks for your help Glenn. Any issues will be in touch.

Comment: glad i could help, please consider accepting the answer.